# First time writing a smart contract , please help me check are there any vulnerability in my code

Tags: contract-development

This is the first time I write a smart contract and I'm going to use it for real application , so I hope there isn't any vulnerability or exploit since smart contract is immutable 
This contract able to receives transaction from any address but only the owner eligible to withdraw

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract EtherTransferTo{
address public owner;

constructor() public {
owner = msg.sender;
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require (msg.sender == owner);
    _;

}

function () payable public {
    // nothing to do!
}

function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
    return address(this).balance;
}

function withdraw(uint amount) onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    require(amount <= this.balance);
    owner.transfer(amount);
    return true;

}


}
```

I know it is stupid to ask for help like this , but there isn't any friends of mine know programming ,  much appreciate if anyone could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not exactly a vulnerability, but something that will put you in a very "uncomfortable" situation at some later point, is the fact that once deployed, you cannot change the `owner` of your contract.

This means that whatever private key you deploy this contract with - you could never replace.

And it leaves you with the following problems:

1. The private key owner retires from the company (for whatever reason), but will forever be able to withdraw money from the contract.
2. The contract is secured by a single key, which if stolen, can lead to the entire fund being drained out. The typical solution for that, is to replace ownership immediately after deployment, from yourself to a multi-sig contract (see example [here](https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet/blob/master/contracts/MultiSigWallet.sol)). With your current implementation, you will not be able to do so.

Second thought, both problems are definitely under the category of *vulnerability*.

The typical solution is to provide an infrastructure for replacing the initial `owner`.

The good news are that you don't have to implement it yourself.

See [`contract Ownable`](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol) by OpenZeppelin.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Btw should I implement safemath library in this contract?

Comment: @jent: what do you mean by "implement safemath library in this contract"??? If you want to implement any other library or contract then  you can go ahead, but it will obviously be independent of this contract. Did you  mean "**use** safemath library in this contract"? If yes, then - do you know what safemath is used for?